# Reviews for first time posters need to improve?

Tags: discussion

So I was wondering how all these first time posts are getting through but the number of First Posts in the review queue is always low or zero.

One reason might be that people are ignoring junk in the review queue and letting it pass. We can't do this!

Look at the history of the reviews:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/history

Example:

- [How to add a printer for a program using wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338368/please-help-with-cups-pdf-printer) <--- THAT IS NOT EVEN A QUESTION, marked "No action needed".

Keep scrolling through the review history, too much *crap* is being "No action needed", what's even worse is that when someone lets that junk through it zeroes out the queue, which means as a reviewer I never get a chance to see the "PLEASE HELP CUPS" stuff to actually improve the question.

Comment: I think this has to be mentioned here. A moderator can "suspend" a reviewer from review queue.

Comment: That was one of my rants in the previous question. I think we need some audits, like SO.

Comment: Well - by clicking on *No action needed* we merely confirm that the question "seems to be valid" (according to the tool tip) - which is rather easily fulfilled. BTW: the history link shows (for me) only my own reviews :-))

Comment: @guntbert only the first page of mine has only 6 NaN so, there is always room to improvements ;)

Comment: @jokerdino you really feel like doing everything you do + reviewing what reviewers do?