# Should we get review audits?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

Today (2013-12-11), in 3-4 occasions, [regulars in chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201/2013/12/11) expressed their concerns that users do not know how to use the site. Is not surprising considering that our eternal September hasn't ended yet, and senior members on AU aren't enough for the amount of new users that reach us. [My previous proposal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7295/169736) was more or less left without further discussion with +5/-3 votes and an answer of Eliah, so I would want to bring this up again.

[Do we need already the reviews audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/213575)?

#### Reasons (?):

- We are over Super User amount of questions per day, and SU has it.
- We are more popular (aka hits) than all but 2 SE sites.
- Our general question quality is bad.
- The quality of the answers is somewhat bad too.
- The amount of (bad) questions are almost reaching the amount of answers.
- We get a better Ask Ubuntu, and we could be more alert when reviewing stuff
- This has been pointed out already several times, [even Moderators](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8421/169736)
- reasons...

#### Cons:

- Users will ask why they failed a review audit
- Any other?

Comment: why are "We get a better (?) Ask Ubuntu" and "Users will ask why they failed a review audit" cons?

Comment: @kalina because reasons

Comment: All the questions linked seem to have been resolved? AFAICT that's what we use the chat room for no?

Comment: @JorgeCastro yeah, that was the one that we catch. But what about the ones that miss completely our radar? Problems that happens everywhere in the site. We need as many eyes on the site as possible, and I think the audits is a nice addition to check if the reviewers are doing things right too. I swear I'm learning DB to gather proof.

Comment: One thing you can do is start writing data.se queries for things so that we can start actioning on them.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I would love to know where the problem is so I can generate the data, but if I can't trust reviewers are doing their stuff right, then no matter what actions I take if my sources are poisoned with bad data.

Comment: I've brought this up before, perhaps merge? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7234/reviews-for-first-time-posters-need-to-improve

Comment: Could you explain what you actually mean by "review audits." None of the linked questions explain this. Are you proposing that moderators do some kind of manual auditing of past reviews or some kind of automated process? You mentioned that this is something other sites have. Do you mean the "honeypot" review items that catch people approving junk?

Comment: @andrewsomething The last thing you mentioned. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/213575

Comment: yes, because of robo reviewers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've turned these on. I've also enabled automatic review *bans* to assist Oli's efforts [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8421/reviewers-need-to-be-mindful-of-their-actions) - we'll be keeping a sharp eye on how these play out in practice, since they may need some tweaking.

Remember: review audits are meant to be helpful, a tool for teaching new reviewers what is expected and maybe staving off fatigue in experienced reviewers.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Where do you expect reports about experience with the audits?

Comment: Post them here on meta, @guntbert - tags support, review, audits

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example of some problems, this is just a sampling from the first page of the review queue:

[image]

Now, if people are inexperienced reviewers or just suck at reviews, then that's okay I guess. New people learn and all that.

The problem is that most times "New Posts" is either 0 or single digits, if whoever clears out that queue and says "ubuntu 13.10 freeze" is okay then it just goes through, I never even get a chance to see it in my queue to fix it!

Comment: Yes, those are (some of) the problems I want to tackle with this solution. If we bring the hammer down to make reviewers actually do *reviews* will be the best. Remember that it doesn't matter if it has a good title, if the content sucks, too.

Comment: BTW, they are live ;)