# Ask Ubuntu tested me

Tags: support, review

Why Ask Ubuntu tested me while reviewing close votes?What was the purpose of this kind of tests?

[image]

Comment: Just to say - this is part of the review-audit system as explained here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7812/should-we-get-review-audits

Comment: It doesn't trust you! :O  (kidding)

Comment: Me too! Maybe is a secondary effect of the activity in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits?lq=1 ? They increased the tests?

Comment: I already answer three of these in total today and correctly. Make them more difficult, random and drop the hint message (:

Comment: I was tested yesterday too. It was easy, it started with the word "F*ck".

Answer (score 5):

This would explain most of your doubts but in summary is a test if you are paying attention (and doing a good job) to the review queue.

- [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/213575)